# PropertyGrid with Custom PropertyDescriptor

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I've been struggling quite a bit to get custom PropertyDescriptors to work the way I want with a PropertyGrid.

The premise:

- I have a class called "Animal" which contains the properties `Age`, `Type`, `Location`, and `Name`.
- I have another class called "AnimalGroup" which contains a `List<Animal>` where animals are stored.  The class member that contains this list is called `Members`.
- In the UI of the program, a `PropertyGrid` form element will list off the Animals in the AnimalGroup that is assigned to the PropertGrid's `SelectedObject` property.

The third bullet I can get working quite easily (see image below).

[image: PropertyGrid showing the members of an AnimalGroup.]

The AnimalGroup class implements the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface to achieve the listing functionality of the Animals in its `Members` class member.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the image above, the property value is simply the value returned from the Animal's ToString method.

**I'd like to allow users the ability to edit the members of each Animal in the PropertyGrid (Age, Type, Location, and Name).  How can I achieve this?**  I assume there will need to be a custom editor of some type.  Honestly, however, I have no idea where to get started as Googling hasn't turned up much for this.

Here are the tutorials I followed to get to this point:

- [Add (Remove) Items to (from) PropertyGrid at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9280/Add-Remove-Items-to-from-PropertyGrid-at-Runtime)
- [Using PropertyGrid with a dictionary object](http://www.differentpla.net/content/2005/02/using-propertygrid-with-dictionary) (this tutorial seems really old)

And if you need it, here's my code (using .NET 4.0):

**Animal.cs**

```
public class Animal
{
    private String _Name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    private String _Type;

    public String Type
    {
        get { return _Type; }
        set { _Type = value; }
    }
    private String _Age;

    public String Age
    {
        get { return _Age; }
        set { _Age = value; }
    }
    private String _Location;

    public String Location
    {
        get { return _Location; }
        set { _Location = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name + " - " + this.Type;
    }
}
```

**AnimalGroup.cs**

```
public class AnimalGroup : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public List<Animal> Members;

    public AnimalGroup()
    {
        this.Members = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor[] pds = new PropertyDescriptor[this.Members.Count];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Animal a in this.Members)
        {
            pds[i] = new AnimalPropertyDescriptor(a, attributes);

            i++;
        }


        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(pds);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return this.GetProperties(new Attribute[0]);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this.Members;
    }
}
```

**AnimalPropertyDescriptor.cs**

```
public class AnimalPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private Animal property;

    public AnimalPropertyDescriptor(Animal target, Attribute[] attrs)
        : base(target.Name, attrs)
    {
        this.property = target;
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return property;
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false;  }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this.property.GetType(); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        // Not relevant.
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        this.property = (Animal)value;
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

FYI, I am aware that the code is a bit ridiculous (Animals with names, animal groups, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a converter:

```
internal class AnimalConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter {

  public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                   CultureInfo culture, 
                                   object value,
                                   Type destinationType) {

    if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is Animal) {
      Animal a = (Animal)value;
      return a.ToString();
    }
    return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
  }
}
```

Then decorate your animal:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(AnimalConverter))]
public class Animal {...}
```

Found this Code Project [Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert) helpful.