# How can I use a password char in a DevExpress PropertyGridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

If I assign an object to PropertyGridControl.SelectedObjuect [then I can use [PasswordPropertyTextAttribute(true)] for the password property](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q528743) and it works great.

However I pass an object that implements ICustomTypeDescriptor as follows and this has no effect:

```
AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
{
    AttributeCollection attrColl = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    Attribute [] attrs = new Attribute[attrColl.Count + 1];
    attrColl.CopyTo(attrs, 0);
    attrs[attrs.Length-1] = new PasswordPropertyTextAttribute(true);
    return new AttributeCollection(attrs);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? We're using Windows Forms & C#.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892064/propertygrid-with-custom-propertydescriptor

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that an incorrect method is used to achieve the required result. As stated in the ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes MSDN article, this method returns a collection of custom attributes for this instance of a component.
However, to assign an attribute to a property of the target object, you need to override the ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties method. In your specific case, you can implement the method in the following manner:

```
 PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true);
            return UpdateProperties(props);
        }
         PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, true);
            return UpdateProperties(props);
        }
         private PropertyDescriptorCollection UpdateProperties(PropertyDescriptorCollection props)
        {
            List<PropertyDescriptor> newProps = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            PropertyDescriptor current;
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                current = prop;
                if (prop.Name == "UserPassword")
                    current = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(typeof(UserInfo), prop, new Attribute[] { new PasswordPropertyTextAttribute(true) });
                newProps.Add(current);
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(newProps.ToArray()); ;
        }
```